# How do I get my code to run in a way that won't cut off the words(strings)?

Tags: c++, procedural-programming

The goal of this program should be to produce a output string such that:

1. The output string **+** spaces in between == the width.
2. The strings are **not** cut off. So, it gives out complete words per line.

This is what I have so far:

```
int main()
{
    int width= 15;
    vector<string> line;
    line.push_back("Hello");
    line.push_back("My");
    line.push_back("Name");
    line.push_back("Is");
    line.push_back("John");

    auto s = line.front();
    for (auto i = std::size_t {1}; i < line.size(); ++i) s += ' ' + line[i];


    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i+=width+1)
    {
        s.insert(i,"\n");
    }

    cout<<s;

}
```

**I wan't to add spaces in between the words evenly so the last string won't get cutoff and it moves to the next line.**

This is similar to the question of [C++ text full justification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183952/c-text-full-justification)
**but I want to correct my own implementation to the solution of this problem  .**

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand, you want it to print
"Hello My Name Is
John" with "John" being on a new line?

Comment: Are you trying to make the sentence fit in the console width?

Comment: Maybe this is what are you looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983008/how-to-print-justified-text-in-the-console-using-modern-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is you're inserting the new line inside the string after it has already been formed, thus possibly cutting a word down to the new line.

It would be better to check if the string's length would become bigger than your line's desired width if you insert a new word before adding another word to it.

This is what I could come up with

```
int main()
{
    int width= 15;
    vector<string> line;
    line.push_back("Hello");
    line.push_back("My");
    line.push_back("Name");
    line.push_back("Is");
    line.push_back("John");

    std::string s {};
    for (int i {0}; i < line.size(); ++i)
        {
            if( (s + line[i] + " ").size() <= width)
            {
                s += line[i] + " ";
            }
            else
            {
                s += "\n" + line[i] + " ";
                width += width;
            }
        }
    cout<<s;
}
```